# Mikael's Crucible stopping effects

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Mikael's crucible stop suppresses as well, when used? It wasn't in the description of the item, but almost every other debuff is.

Comment: Hm. For sure it won't work on yourself (suppression cuts abilities, including item ones), but I don't know if you can remove suppression from someone else with it.

Comment: @Gnoupi Suppression does cut abilities - all except one. The active of Quicksilver Sash. Thats why it's the only item that says Removes All Debuffs (including suppress).

Comment: @Pana - ah, yes, forgot the one, of course.

Comment: @Gnoupi kind of late, but as an added note, any abilities that break CC (Alistar's ult, Olaf's ult, Gangplank's W) can be used under suppression to break it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crucible **does not** remove Suppresses.

Check the wiki for Quicksilver Sash. It says it removes ALL DEBUFFs and goes on to explain that it includes Suppresses.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash

Mikael's Crucible however does not say ALL DEBUFFs, instead it states the debuffs that it removes (stuns, roots, taunts, fears, silences and slows). It's a thin line but you can see the difference.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mikael%27s_Crucible

I think it's the same for summoner spell cleanse (where it doesn't say all debuffs either) because it doesn't remove suppress either.